# SQL query to get all records with certain parent IDs and two additional conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I am working on a table which stores different bus routes. Each route can go through different locations (`StationId`) and the order in which it goes through each of them is determined by the column `StationOrder`.

The table looks like this:

```
RouteId | StationId | StationOrder |
------------------------------------
1       | 1         | 2
1       | 2         | 3
1       | 4         | 1
3       | 1         | 1
3       | 2         | 3
3       | 3         | 2
```

What I know is the routes that I'm interested in. In this case those are routes with id 1 and 3. I also know which is the starting Station, StationId 1 what I need to select is all StationIds which have `StationOrder` number higher than the `StationOrder` number for `StationId` 1.

I would show what I've tried so far but basically, since the table contains more routes than just two those I know how to select the desired routes:

```
SELECT RS.StationId FROM RouteStations AS RS
WHERE RS.RouteId IN (1,3)
```

But when it comes to the second part where I need to select all `StationId`s with `StationOrder` number higher than the StationOrder number for StationId 1 for each route my SQL knowledge comes short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I need to select is all StationIds which have StationOrder number
>   higher than the StationOrder number for StationId 1

Put these conditions in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT RS.StationId 
FROM RouteStations AS RS
WHERE 
  RS.RouteId IN (1,3)
  AND
  RS.StationOrder > (
    select StationOrder 
    FROM RouteStations 
    WHERE RouteId = RS.RouteId AND StationId = 1
  )
```

If you don't want duplicates in the results, use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RS.StationId
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @forpas answer, you can do a join to table itself.

```
SELECT s.StationId 
FROM RouteStationsS s
    INNER JOIN RouteStation s2 on s.RouteId = s2.RouteId and s.StationOrder > s2.StationOrder
WHERE s2.RouteId IN (1, 3) and s2.StationId = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with window functions:

```
select rs.*
from (select rs.*,
             min(case when stationid = 1 then stationorder end) over (partition by routeid) as stationorder_1
      from routestations rs
     ) rs
where routeid in (1, 3) and
      stationorder > stationorder_1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the routeId is not important, then remove it from the inline view...

```
SELECT a.*
FROM routes a
JOIN (
        SELECT  routeId
        ,       stationId
        ,       max(stationOrder) maxOrder
        FROM routes
        WHERE stationId = 1
        GROUP BY routeId
        ,        stationId
        ) b ON a.routeId = b.routeId
WHERE a.stationOrder > b.maxOrder
```